# using global inside of function to get variable from included file. PHP

Tags: php

Really simple I just think it's me.

this is file 1.php

```
if(ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
{
    $item_id = "Hello";
}
else
{
    //Something
}
```

this is file 2.php

```
function item_show(){

        $item_query = "SELECT title FROM tbl_items WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($item_id) . "' ";

}
```

Now my question is how do I get the value of `$item_id` from 1.php inside the function in 2.php ?

To add file 1.php and file 2.php are both included in index.php

Comment: is file2.php included in file1.php?

Comment: file 1.php and file 2.php are both included in index.php

Comment: Just keep in mind that included files in PHP work as if they were copied and pasted there, so use your variables and methods as you would if they were all one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you just passing it as a function argument like this?

```
item_show($item_id);
```

or (the very hacky and not recommended):

```
function item_show(){
        global $item_id;
        $item_query = "SELECT title FROM tbl_items WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($item_id) . "' ";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose index.php includes the files following the order file1.php, file2.php.

In this case, you can use the following code in file2.php:

```
function item_show() {
  global $item_id;
  $item_query = "SELECT title FROM tbl_items WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($item_id) . "' ";
}
```

Comment: oh so I call global in the function not in the included file of origin ?

Comment: @Oliver Bayes-Shelton: A function cannot access global variables, if they are not declared. Super global variables (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$GLOBALS`) are different because they can be accessed without to declare them.

Answer (score 1):

```
function item_show($item_id){}
```

or

```
function item_show()
{
    global $item_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `require` to include the code from 1.php.
2. In 1.php, return the value of $item_id.
3. Call the function in 1.php from 2.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$GLOBALS['item_id']
```

in both files, instead of

```
$item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function item_show()
{
    global $item_id;
}
```

but I heard that using global is not a good coding method.

Comment: You're right, globals are generally not good. You could easily modify this function to pass the item id as a parameter instead, which would be much better.